# Is there a way to determine the memory usage per application in weblogic?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, weblogic

We are running weblogic and appear to have a memory leak - we eventually run out of heap space.

We have 5 apps (5 war deployments) on the server.

Can you think of a way to gather memory usage on a per application basis?

(Then we can concentrate our search by looking through the code in the appropriate app.)

I have run jmap to get a heap dump and loaded the results in jvisualvm but it's unclear where the bulk of objects have come from - for example Strings.

I was thinking that weblogic perhaps uses separate classloaders per application and so we may be able to figure something out via that route...

Comment: Try something like NewRelic, they have a free trial period which should be enough to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using Eclipse MAT, it gives hint of memory leaks, among others features